# Datadriven framework ->reading from .ods file

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng, openoffice.org

TestNG has built in support for DATADRIVEN framework. I implemented datadriven framework by reading data from excel file using jxl api. But now I want to read data from a .ods format file (OpenSourceData Spreadsheet) is there any support/code available for this format?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use ODFtoolkit library: 
http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/

You can also unzip the ods file, then parse content.xml...